# One Way Boolean Function

Tags: cr.crypto-security, one-way-function

If one way functions exist, what would the truth table of a one way boolean function look like?

Comment: What do you mean by “Boolean function” in this question?  Clearly you do not mean a function which takes a value in {0,1}.

Comment: @ Tsuyoshi: Yes, that is correct, {0,1}.

Comment: Then I do not think that this question is suitable on cstheory.stackexchange.com, which is a place for research-level questions.

Answer (score 4):

There exist no boolean one way functions, since for a boolean function, you can always guess a preimage of the output, and with high probability, you'll be right.

Comment: So you can guess the preimage of a 256 bit (N imput) boolean function ?

Comment: If you can guess the pre-image of the output with high probability then SAT would be in BPP.

Comment: @ William Hird, one-wayness is an asymptotic notion, so a function may be one way, but easily reversible at any concrete n.

Comment: @M.Alaggan One way ness requires that the function be hard to invert on random inputs. SAT is hard only. When the fraction of satisfying assignments is small. But such a formula is not one way since on a random input, the function value will almost certainly be 0. So Or Meir's solution is correct (it is a standard textbook answer).

Comment: @ Martin & Adam: Yes I am talking about a function hard to invert on random imputs, the output will of course be 1 half the time and zero half the time. Why the downvotes here, what is wrong or simple about my question?

Comment: William, one-wayness requires that given the image of a random input a polytime TM cannot guess a preimage with probability greater than $1-\delta(n)$ where $\delta(n)$ goes to 0 superpolynomially fast. But with a boolean function you can guess an input from the larger of the two preimages and you'll be right with probability $\geq 1/2$.

Comment: Maybe you're asking for boolean functions which are hard to invert with probability  $(1+\epsilon(n))/2$ where $\epsilon(n)$ is inverse polynomial. The Goldreich-Levin theorem constructs such a "hard-core predicate" from any one-way permutation: [Luca's notes](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~luca/pacc/lecture08.pdf)

Comment: @ Sasho: OK , thank you. I will reformulate my question so that it meets the requirement of a research level question.